# SQL JOIN table data with incremental variable with max value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm wondering on how to get a join query of two auxiliary tables to get a complete set of production line test slots "names" or "tags"

The first auxiliar table has information on how many slots a certain machine has. And it looks like

```
Machine Types AUX table
------------------------------------------------------
MachineTypeID   SlotNumber
1               5
2               3
3               10
```

The second one has the list of machine IDs for each production line. Looks like:

```
Lines AUX table
----------------------------------
LineID   MachineID   MachineTypeID
1        PR00231     1
1        PR00049     2
2        PR00147     1
2        PR00017     2
2        PR00178     3
```

I don't know **how to build a list of "MachineID+SlotNum" tag** using the list of MachineIDs and the number of slots that each machine has.

Expected result, when filtering by line, would be like:

```
LINE 2 list of slotsTAGs:
-----------------------------------
PR00147_Slot1
PR00147_Slot2
PR00147_Slot3
PR00147_Slot4
PR00147_Slot5
PR00017_Slot1
PR00017_Slot2
PR00017_Slot3
PR00178_Slot1
PR00178_Slot2
PR00178_Slot3
PR00178_Slot4
PR00178_Slot5
PR00178_Slot6
PR00178_Slot7
PR00178_Slot8
PR00178_Slot9
PR00178_Slot10
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate this result, you need to form a numbers table which consists of the numbers from 1 to `MAX(SlotNumber)`. In this query I've used a recursive CTE to do that. This can then be JOINed to the `Lines` and `Types` table to form the list:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT  MAX(SlotNumber) AS MaxSlot FROM Types
), cte2 (Slot) AS 
(SELECT 1 AS Slot
 UNION ALL
 SELECT Slot+1 FROM cte2 WHERE Slot < (SELECT MaxSlot FROM cte1))
SELECT CONCAT(l.MachineID, '_Slot', c.Slot) AS Slots
FROM Lines l
JOIN Types t ON t.MachineTypeID = L.MachineTypeID
JOIN cte2 c ON c.Slot <= t.SlotNumber
WHERE l.LineID = 2
ORDER BY l.MachineId, c.Slot
```

Output:

```
Slots
PR00017_Slot1
PR00017_Slot2
PR00017_Slot3
PR00147_Slot1
PR00147_Slot2
PR00147_Slot3
PR00147_Slot4
PR00147_Slot5
PR00178_Slot1
PR00178_Slot2
PR00178_Slot3
PR00178_Slot4
PR00178_Slot5
PR00178_Slot6
PR00178_Slot7
PR00178_Slot8
PR00178_Slot9
PR00178_Slot10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=8af590afbf173f6ada0c1f6f8df5a671)

Comment: Hi Nick, your solution is working fine, thanks! In fact, I have added your nested cte to my cte chain and finally I'm getting good results of performance of all Slots of a certain line, even the disabled ones that are not reporting any activity.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code-

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[Machine Types AUX]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [Machine Types AUX]

CREATE TABLE [Machine Types AUX]
(
MachineTypeID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT [PK_MachineTypesAUX] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
SlotNumber INT NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO [Machine Types AUX] (SlotNumber)
VALUES (5),(3),(10)

IF OBJECT_ID('[Lines AUX]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [Lines AUX]

CREATE TABLE [Lines AUX]
(
LineID INT NOT NULL,
MachineID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
MachineTypeID INT NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO [Lines AUX] (LineID,MachineID,MachineTypeID)
VALUES (1,'PR00231',1),
(1,'PR00049',2),
(2,'PR00147',1),
(2,'PR00017',2),
(2,'PR00178',3)

--SELECT * FROM [Machine Types AUX]
--SELECT * FROM [Lines AUX]

--EXPECTED_RESULT:
SELECT CONCAT(MachineID,'_Slot',SlotNumber) AS slotsTAGs 
FROM [Machine Types AUX] T INNER JOIN [Lines AUX] T1 ON T.MachineTypeID=T1.MachineTypeID
```